# I got java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "" with extending zero at last eg:- 2014-11-26 12:22:44.0

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

Please help me with the following code. I got unparseable date exception.

```
public static Date getUtilDateFromString(String date) throws ParseException {
        return getUtilDateFromString(date, null);
    }

    public static Date getUtilDateFromString(String date, String format)
            throws ParseException {
        if (format == null || "".equals(format)) {
            format = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss";
        }

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        return dateFormat.parse(date);
    }
```

Comment: can u show me what u;re passing in date string?

Answer (score 0):

The Date format should be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S` since you're dealing with milliseconds. Your date pattern has mistakes too.

This works:

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").parse("2014-11-26 12:22:44.0"));
```

Output:

> Wed Nov 26 12:22:44 CAT 2014

Comment: I don't want to deal with the miliseconds. I call it like that only getUtilDateFromString("2014/12/06 12:26:11") but not able to understand how it gives unparseable date exception in this format 2014-11-26 12:22:44.0

Comment: Look at your date format, the first date are separated by `/` and the other by `-`. How do you expect your `SimpleDateFormat` to parse your date if the date string does not conform to your date pattern `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss`?

Answer (score 0):

I would check the `String date` variable you are using, it seems that it does not fit the format you are trying to implement.

For example if you call `getUtilDateFromString("2014-12-06 12:26:11")` it will not work because the SimpleDateFormat will be expecting a `String date` with the format `"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"`.

If you call `getUtilDateFromString("2014/12/06 12:26:11")` will work perfectly fine because the
`String date` fits the format `"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I call it like that only getUtilDateFromString("2014/12/06 12:26:11") but not able to understand how it gives unparseable date exception in this format 2014-11-26 12:22:44.0

Comment: Not sure I understood you correctly, you are calling the method like this: getUtilDateFromString("2014-11-26 12:22:44.0")? if thats the case you need to call it like this: getUtilDateFromString("2014-11-26 12:22:44.0", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"). The date string must match the format string for it to be parseable. If you don't specify a format string when you call the method, by default it will use the format "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", thats why it gives you the exception